# Найти ошибку в программе

Tags: c, сортировка

Помогите найти ошибку в коде. Функция должна сортировать массив длины n по возрастанию. Однако делает это она как-то криво, не всегда получается нужный результат.

```
void swap(int*a, int*b){
    int c = *a;
    *a=*b;
*b=c;}
void quicksort(int *a, int n) {
    int i=0;
    int j=n-1;
    if(j==1){
        if(a[j-1] > a[j]){
    swap(&a[j-1], &a[j]);}}
    else{
int mid = a[j/2];
    do{
        while(a[i] < mid) {
            i++;
        }
        while(a[j] > mid) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i <= j) {
        swap(&a[i], &a[j]);}
            i++;
            j--;
    }while (i <= j);
    if(j > 0) {
        quicksort(a, j);
    }
    if (i < n) {
        quicksort(&a[i], n-i);
    }
}}
```

Comment: Отлаживать пробовали?

Comment: Не очень понимаю значение слова отлаживать. Полный код без проблем скомпилировался, проверил его на разных тестах, всё было отсортировано правильно, кроме последнего: 
4 9 8 6 9
9 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
5 67 45 34 12 90 
7 5 6 7 4 3 2 1
8 10 7 8 6 4 3 2 1
10 7 6 43 31 54 100 11 12 14 1 . Первое число - длина массива, остальные его элементы.

Comment: Вероятнее всего, что-то не так с выбором среднего элемента, относительно которого я запускаю quicksort. Вот, что выдала программа в последнем тесте 6 7 14 31 1 43 11 12 100 54  . Видно, что фрагментарно отсортировано. Не могу понять, где программа сбивается

Comment: Отлаживать  - передать функции небольшой массив, который можно увидеть глазами целиком, и пройти программу по шагам, используя точки остановки, контролируя переменные, чтобы отловить момент неправильной работы

Comment: Элемент-разделитель можно выбирать любым образом, на правильность работы это не повлияет

Comment: Смущает i <=j для обмена. Не лишнего ли продвинутся индексы. Просто меньше

Comment: Все равно ломается, даже при i<j

Comment: Попробуйте опорный элемент поменять с последним и без него (последнего )выполнить разделение, потом поставить на место (j)

Comment: Мне кажется, я понял, в чем ошибка. Иногда после того, как цикл do while заканчивается, и запускаются 2 рекурсии по оставшимся половинам, опорный элемент не захватывается в последующие сортировки и остается на своем месте. Попробую переделать программу